# new created UIImageViews do not show up when added as subview

Tags: ios, uiview, addsubview

upon a tap, I want to let a few UIImageView objects appear on an underlaying UIView.
So I created the following action:

```
- (IBAction)startStars: (id) sender
{
UIView* that = (UIView*) sender;  // an UIButton, invisible, but reacting to Touch Down events
int tag = that.tag;

UIView* page = [self getViewByTag:mPages index:tag];  // getting a page currently being viewed
if ( page != nil )
{

    int i;
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some.png"];

    for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i )
    {   
        // create a new UIImageView at the position of the tapped UIView
        UIImageView* zap = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:that.frame];
        // assigning the UIImage
        zap.image = image;

        // make a modification to the position so we can see all instances
        CGPoint start = that.layer.frame.origin;
        start.x += i*20;
        zap.layer.position = start;

        [page addSubview:zap];   // add to the UIView
        [zap setNeedsDisplay];   // please please redraw
        [zap release];           // release, since page will retain zap

    }
    [image release];
}
}
```

Unfortunately, nothing shows up. The code gets called, the objects created, the image is loaded, even the properties are as expected.
Page itself is a real basic UIView, created with interface builder to contain other views and controls.

Still, nothing of this can be seen....

Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong? Do I need to set the alpha property (or others)?

Thanks

Zuppa

Comment: My first thought is there is something going wrong in your `getViewByTag:index:` function. Could you post that as well?

Comment: Indeed. That was the case. I never thought of that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things I would check:

- Logging to make sure this section of code is actually being called.
- Use the designated initializer for `UIImageView`:

  ```
  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
  ```

  This will ensure that your new view has the correct size for the image - what are the relative sizes of `zap` and your image? It could be out of the frame.
- Ensure that the image actually exists and is created
- Try not adjusting the layer properties, but setting the `center` of the image view instead. In fact, in the first instance don't adjust it at all and just see if you can see anything. I'm not sure but I think `position` might be moving the layer *within* the view so could be moving your image out of sight. Try:

  ```
  CGPoint newCenter = that.frame.origin;
  newCenter.y += zap.bounds.size.height/2;
  newCenter.x += i*20;
  zap.center = origin;
  ```
- `setNeedsDisplay` is not required. Obviously from your comments it was an act of desparation!

Comment: stupid me, the view I was adding it to, was one currently not visible (I have several "pages" and instead of page 7 it was page 0, still your answers gave me more insight to the theme

Answer (score 0):

Is your UIImage nil?
You don't need to have the .png extension for `imageNamed:` to work. It might not even work correctly if you put it in, I'm not sure. You're also overreleasing your image. `imageNamed:` returns an autoreleased image so there is no reason to call release on the image unless you're also calling retain on it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I see a potential error: on second invocation you will re-add another copy, so take care about  removing subviews before adding anew copy. Yu can alternatively move a previous view.

99% of my cases about non-visible views with images are wrong names, so as suggested, load using a temp var:

UIImage img = [UIImage imageNamed..];

and test img.